# Does document creation failure count as a write in firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am in a situation where I have to create a document if it didn't exist in a collection, or delete it if exists.

In order to solve this situation, I have thought to:

```
 1. Read doc
 2. If !doc.exists -> create it
 3. Else -> delete it
```

But, maybe, it will be cheaper to do:

```
 1. Try to create a doc.
 2. If fails because it exists, delete it.
```

I have been looking the documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing but I don't find anything related to unseccesful operations. Will I be charged with a document creation if it fails?

Comment: For issues surrounding billing, if it's not covered in the documentation, you should ask Firebase support for the best possible answer.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `create`, though failed, is still counts as a write operation.

Unfortunately I am unable to provide steps to observe this behavior. The response is based on my own use of Firestore and seeing write counts increase with failed writes. It is not clear if all failure types will increase the write count or what the needed conditions are. Unfortunately this information is not available from GCP documentation.

Comment: How did you reach this conclusion?  It's not covered explicitly in the documentation.  It's also worth knowing that there are a lot of different ways that a write can fail, and they might not all consider billing at all.

Comment: I have seen the counts increment with some failures, and yes you are correct that there are many different types of failures. Though without it explicitly documented it is a bit of a guessing game. IMO since some are counted as writes, assume they are all are for the sake of billing estimation.

Comment: For the purpose of crafting a complete answer, I suggest providing instructions that anyone can reproduce that effectively proves your answer.  Otherwise, we don't really know what exactly to expect here.

Comment: I am sorry I don't have time to put all that together, I guess I should retract my answer then. And to be honest, as you well know as a Firestore consultant, when it comes to gcp there is SOOOOO much we don't exactly know what to expect.

Comment: You actually can't delete an accepted answer on SO unless you appeal to the moderators by flagging it.  But at the very least, you can edit the question to say that you do not have steps to observe this behavior.